# while condition true if value appears in list of tuples

Tags: python, networkx

I'm new to Python and got stuck while implementing an algorithm for drawing graphs. I have a list of tuples that contain certain nodes and their 'level' (for layering). Initially that looks like this:

`[(0, 10), (1, 'empty'), (2, 'empty'), (3, 'empty'), (4, 'empty'), (5, 'empty'), (6, 'empty'), (7, 'empty'), (8, 'empty'), (9, 'empty')]` (node,level)

Now I need to assign levels to these nodes as long as any node has no level, respective the 'empty' attribute.

I tried several structures of possible while conditions, that syntactically weren't wrong but semantically didn't make any sense, since the while loop didn't terminate:

```
while (True for node, level in g.nodes(data='level') if level == 'empty'):
```

or

```
while ( 'empty' in enumerate(g.nodes(data='level') ):
```

and certain other similar constructs, that didn't work and I don't remember..

Until now it doesn't seem clear to me why this won't work - python didn't even enter the while loop with these conditions. Can you explain me why and hand me a clue how to fix it?

**hint:**
g.nodes(data='level') is a networkx function, that returns the upper list of tuples

Comment: For clarification, are you saying that you want to give a level to each node without one, where every node is represented as `[node_number, level_number]`?

Comment: right, [(node_number, level_number)] - there are some more conditions how to assign these levels within this loop, which I've omitted for simplification and focus. Assigning the level-attribute to the node then happens with ```nx.set_node_attributes(g, { node : level }, 'level')```

Comment: Can you clarify why you are trying to do this with a ``while`` loop? Since there is only a fixed number of nodes, simply iterating over all nodes once (via ``for``) and setting their level ensures that every node has a level. A ``while`` loop os only useful if the levels cannot be assigned linearly, or the graph grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the things you have in the parentheses are *generator expressions* and they just always evaluate to `True`.

You have the right idea but maybe need to learn a bit more about these expressions and what to do with them. In your first suggestions, here is what I _ think_ you mean:

```py
while any(level == 'empty' for node, level in g.nodes(data='level')):
  ...
```

In your version, what you do is create a *generator expression* that will container a number of `True` values, one for each level that is `empty`. However, even if that generator expression will have no elements in it, it is in and of itself not an empty object, and thus it evaluates to `True`.

You can try this out:

```py
bool([]) # --> False because empty sequence
bool(list(range(1, -10))) # --> False because empty sequence
bool((i for i in range(1,-10))) # --> True because non-None generator expression
```

So you need to turn your generator expression into a truth value that actually reflects whether it has any true elements in it, and that's what the `any` function does: Take an iterator (or a generator expression) and return true if any of its elements are true.

Comment: What makes you think that they are generators instead of tuples?

Comment: @LucasNg Because ``(... for ... in ... if ...)`` is the syntax for a generator expression?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I did not read his answer fully and assumed he was talking about the nested tuples.

Comment: This succeeded, thank you so much! I think those 'propositional expressions' are very useful to keep in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make an elemental check do your searching for you.  Instead, concentrate on extracting exactly the values you need to check.  Let's start with the list of tuples as

```
g = [(0, 10), (1, 'empty'), (2, 'empty'), (3, 'empty'), (4, 'empty'),
     (5, 'empty'), (6, 'empty'), (7, 'empty'), (8, 'empty'), (9, 'empty')]
```

Now get a list of only the levels:

```
level = [node[1] for node in g]
```

Now, your check is simply

```
while "empty" in level:
    # Assign levels as appropriate
    # Repeat the check for "empty"
    level = [node[1] for node in g]
```

If you're consistently updating the main graph, `g`, then fold the level extraction into the `while`:

```
while "empty" in [node[1] for node in g]:
    # Assign levels
```

---

Originally, your `while` failed because you return `True` so long as there's anything in `g`:

```
while (True for node, level in ...)
```

You have a good approach, but made it one level too complex, and got stuck with `True`.

Your `enumerate` attempt fails because you search for a string in an enumerator, rather than in its returned values.  You could make a list of the returned values, but then we're back where we started, with a list of tuples.  This would compare "empty" against each tuple, and fail to find the desired string -- it's one level farther down.

Comment: Concerning "Originally, your `while` failed [...]": There doesn't have to be anything in `g`. The expression is a generator expression, which is truthy even when empty: `bool((_ for _ in [])) is True`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers may be best. But the specific test you requested can be written a few ways:

This is similar to what you had, but creates a list instead of a generator. The list will evaluate as `False` if it is empty, but the generator doesn't.

```
while [True for node, level in g.nodes(data='level') if level == 'empty']:
   ...
```

This is an equally effective version. The list just has to be empty or not; it doesn't matter whether the elements are `True` or `False` or something else:

```
while [node for node, level in g.nodes(data='level') if level == 'empty']:
   ...
```

Or you can use Python's `any` function, which was made for this and will be a little more efficient (it stops checking elements after the first match). This can use a generator or a list.

```
while any(level == 'empty' for node, level in g.nodes(data='level')):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to assign levels for each if one is empty then a simple for loop should suffice:

```
data = [(0, 10), (1, 'empty'), (2, 'empty'), (3, 'empty'), (4, 'empty'), (5, 'empty'), (6, 'empty'), (7, 'empty'), (8, 'empty'), (9, 'empty')]
output = []

for node, level in data:
    if level == 'empty':
        level = ? #question mark is whatever level logic you wish to insert
    output.append((node, level))
```

Comment: You should not override the builtin name `input` with your own definition; this can cause problems if s/he tries to use the builtin

Comment: it's not sufficient as there can be more then one iteration until all nodes have been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It is often more Pythonic just to use a for loop:

```py
nodes = [(0, 10),
         (1, 'empty'),
         (2, 'empty'),
         (3, 'empty'),
         (4, 'empty'),
         (5, 'empty'),
         (6, 'empty'),
         (7, 'empty'),
         (8, 'empty'),
         (9, 'empty')]

for node in nodes:
    if node[1]=="empty":
        node[1] = set_level_func() # customise this function as you wish
```